LWC email pop up button


I'm writing LWC code, and I want to add a button to display an email pop-up like the red line in the image. Is there a library with such email sending functionality?

Are you looking for a SMTP client Javascript library that could send emails past Salesforce? There are a number of such by now (SmtpJS, EmailJS & Co.), but neither do I believe this makes any sense in a Salesforce context nor do I know, if they will work. Will LWS or Locker like it? What about CORS. But most importantly: In which business process would this make sense? Please add your use case to the question.
